# Why won't my readline advance to the next line?

Tags: python, readline

Whenever my methods are supposed to be advancing to the next line in a txt file that I am importing, they instead decide to continuously use the same line instead of advancing to the next line in the document.

```
DUMMY = 9999

def readMaster():
     #opens the customers file, sets a variable to whatever line we are on
     infile=open("customers.txt", 'r')
     line=infile.readline()[:-1]

#checks if entered ID is valid. If it is, return their name and balance. if not, return garbage.
     if line!=(""):
         masterID,masterName,balance=line.split(",")
         return int(masterID),masterName,int(balance)
     else:
         masterID=DUMMY
         return masterID,"",0
     infile.close()


 def readTransaction():
     #opens the transactions files
     infile=open("transactions.txt","r")

     #scans through the transactions file. If Item ID is found, return that line
     #if it isn't, return garbage variables.
     line=infile.readline()[:-1]
     if line!=(""):
        itemID,itemName,cost=line.split(",")
        return int(itemID),itemName,int(cost)

     else:
        itemID=DUMMY
        return itemID,"",0
     infile.close()

def updateRecords():

     #creates a new file for us to write to.
     outfile = open("new_master.txt", 'w')

     #pulls in any values we need for calculation

     masterID,masterName,balance = readMaster()
     itemID,itemName,cost=readTransaction()

     #checks to see if the customer's ID matches the ID of the service purchased. To avoid printing multiple lines
     #per person, we use a while loop to continue adding to the balance until the customer didn't buy the next item.
     #Then, asks for the next line in the transaction text.

     if int(itemID)==int(masterID):
         while int(itemID)==int(masterID):
             balance = balance+cost

             return int(itemID),itemName,int(cost)

     # Since the customers.txt and transactions.txt files are both sorted numerically, we check to see
     # if one is greater than the other. If it is, that means a customer didn't make any purchases, so we
      # print that person's line from customers.txt without updating it

    elif itemID>masterID:
         print(masterID+","+masterName+","+balance,file =outfile)


     # If we don't find any transactions for something, an error is printed.

    else:
         print("No record for item",itemID)


     print(masterID + "," + masterName + "," + balance, file=outfile)

     itemID,itemName,cost=readTransaction()

     #Then, we print the customer's ID, name, and new balance to the new text file

     print (masterID+","+masterName+","+balance,file = outfile)
```

Customers.txt

```
207,Ann Wyeth,120
215,David Fisher,89
412,Deb Washington,75
609,Lily Ahn,110
610,Dottie Sturgis, 39
1984,Leslie Jackson,109
1989,Taylor Grandview,55
1999,Roger Nelson,65
2112,Lee Geddy,99
5150,Valerie Edwards,45
7800,John Bongiovi,160
```

transactions.txt

```
207,Formal Styling,55
207,Partial Highlights,65
215,Haircut,29
610,Formal Styling,55
610,Accent Highlights,50
1999,Clipper Cut,19
2112,Haircut with Shampoo,39
5150,Haircut with Styling,45
5150,Partial Highlights,65
5150,Treatments,29
6792,Coloring,150
7800,Haircut,29
```

Comment: You're not looping over the file's contents. In each of your methods your `open`ing the file and then doing a `readline`, so it seems you're asking it to repeatedly open the file and read only the first line.

Comment: My professor's powerpoint says that  readline is supposed to read one line of a document, then read the next line when it is used again. Is that not the case?

Comment: not if you close the file afterwards. when you reopen the file, readline begins again at line 0. you could read the file in a loop or via `readlines` method which reads ALL lines and then process the list of *lines* as needed.

Comment: have you had a chance to look at my suggestion? did it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not looping over the file's contents. In each of your methods your opening the file and then doing a readline, so it seems you're asking it to repeatedly open the file and read only the first line. For example, in `readMaster` you think it's doing:

> opens the customers file, sets a variable to whatever line we are on

But that's not the case. You're opening the file, reading one line of it, checking for a null string, and then returning some tuple before closing the file. No matter how many times you call this method, it will only ever read the first line.

Since you're basically doing the same sort of read operation on both files (returning the `int(line[0]),line[1],int(line[2])` for each `line`, you can use a single method (if you needed to process differently, you could use boolean switch based on the filename, etc.):

```
def readFile(filename):
    # returns data from specified file 
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        lines = [line.trim() for line in infile.readlines()]

    lines = [(int(ln[0]),ln[1],int(ln[2])) for ln.split(',') in lines if ln else (masterID,'',0)]

    return lines
```

I'm not sure what sort of output you expect, but I have some idea this might be what you're after:

```
customers = r'c:\debug\customers.txt'
transactions = r'c:\debug\transactions.txt'
outputFile = r'c:\debug\new_master.txt'
def readFile(filename):
    DUMMY = 9999
    default = [DUMMY,'',0]
    # opens the customers file, and returns a list of tuple OR
    # opens the transactions file and returns a list of tuple
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        lines = [line.strip().split(',') for line in infile.readlines()]
    lines = [ln[:3] if ln else default for ln in lines]
    return lines

def updateRecords():
    """
        checks to see if the customer's ID matches the ID of the service purchased. 
        To avoid printing multiple lines per person, add to the balance for each matching id.
    """
    #pulls in any values we need for calculation
    master = readFile(customers)
    trans = readFile(transactions)
    #creates a new file for us to write to.
    outfile = open(outputFile, 'w')
    for (id,name,bal) in master:
        balance = int(bal)
        balance += sum(int(itmCost) for (itmID,itmName,itmCost) in trans if itmID == id)
        # now we have the balance for THIS id from customer file
        if balance == int(bal):
            # If we don't find any transactions for something, an error is printed.
            # balance hasn't changed, no transaction for this customer, log to console
            print("No record for item {}".format(id))
        # update the new master file:
        outfile.write('{},{},{}\n'.format(id,name,balance))
    outfile.close()
```

And produces the following output file:

```
207,Ann Wyeth,240
215,David Fisher,118
412,Deb Washington,75
609,Lily Ahn,110
610,Dottie Sturgis,144
1984,Leslie Jackson,109
1989,Taylor Grandview,55
1999,Roger Nelson,84
2112,Lee Geddy,138
5150,Valerie Edwards,184
7800,John Bongiovi,189
```